# Problema con una consulta a la base de datos desde Eloquent/PHP

Tags: php, eloquent

Estoy realizando una consulta de SELECT a mi base de datos, pero no consigo lo que quiero he estado leyendo la documentacion del framework, pero no he encontrado la respuesta. Esto es lo que tengo:

```
public function getUpdate(){

    1-$id = $_GET['id'];
    2-var_dump($id);
    3-$user = Users::query()->where('id', '=', $id)->get();
    4-var_dump($user);

    5-return $this->render('admin/update.twig', [
        'user' => $user
    ]);

}
```

En la linea 3 estoy haciendo la consulta, pero me esta retornando todos los usuarios de la base de datos y yo solo necesito el usaurio con el id que pedi. necesito ayuda con eso.

Comment: en que framework estas trabajando? por que no me parece sintáxis de Eloquent

Comment: Soy un poco nuevo en este framework, se llama illuminate/database o pues es lo mismo que eloquent. aqui esta el link de donde estoy leyendo https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/database

Comment: por partes solo para aclarar, no es un framework es una dependencia del framework que se llama Laravel; además noto que estas usando Twig como sistema de plantillas; adjunta por favor que resultado obtienes de usar ese fragmento de código, que resultado o error da

Comment: no me esta dando ningun error, pero me esta arrojando todos los datos de la base de datos, pero solo quiero perdirle uno, y es el de "id" que le doy

Comment: al final en lugar de ->get() usa el método ->first(); revisa la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent busca el apartado de first() también revisa sobre el método find()

Comment: ah vale muchisimas gracias, esa era la documentacion que buscaba, realmente la otra no me ofrecia mucho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estás trabajando el laravel, solo hace esto

```
// retorna null si no encuentra el registro
$user = Users::find($id); 

// Retorna una colección vacía en caso de no encontrar un registro.
$user = Users::where('id', $id)->get();
```

Comment: ya habia encontrado la respuesta, pero de igual forma muchisimas gracias. tu respuesta era la adecuada. Aunque me funciono cambiando el get por el first

Comment: no entendi mucho eso, lo probe y no funciona. Seguire investigando un poco sobre esa dependencia